# Update Samsung S3 to 4.2.2 and does it support API level 17?

Tags: android, api, wifi-transfer

I have my Samsung Galaxy S3 updated to Android 4.2.2. So does it mean my phone supports all features like WiFi Direct and Miracast?

I want to get all the APIs that are available in API level 17 like DisplayManager etc. Is it feasible?

Comment: If your phone is running 4.2.2 then it supports everything 4.2.2 supports.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mobile phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. According to Google's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html) Android 4.2 and 4.2.2 support the [API level](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) 17.